# Is it possible to deliver more than one pass in a .PKPASS file?

Tags: passbook

use case:
A customer bought a flight for his family.
Now he wants to download all boarding passes for his flight at once and store it in passbook.

How can I solve this problem?
Can I add more than one pass descriptions in a pass.json?
Or is it possible to reference more than one pass.json files in the manifest.json?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is No.  You cannot include more than one pass in the pass.json or add a reference that will be recognised by Passbook.

Long answer is that there are a number of things that you could do to make it easier for the user.  These include:

- Send all the passes in a single confirmation email as attachments
- Include links on the back of the passes to the other passes in the same booking
- Include a single link on all passes and in any confirmation mesage / email to a page with links where each pass can be downloaded
- Deliver the passes via an app

The last option would provide you access to [PKAddPassesViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKAddPassesViewController_Ref/PKAddPassesViewController.html) class, which if used with the `addPasses:withCompletionHandler:` of the [PKPassLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPassLibrary_Ref/PKPassLibrary.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PKPassLibrary) class, would allow for multiple passes to be added.

Comment: What do you mean with "Include links on the back of the passes to the other passes in the same booking"?

Comment: As of iOS 7 you can add attributed values containing hyperlinks to back fields. You could simply add a https link to each of the .pkass bundles in the same booking.